# The "is" and "as" operators in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

If the `as` operator in C# can only be used with reference and nullable types, is the same is valid for `is` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely. The `is` operation can be used against any type, since you can always check type equality with any type. It's semantically the same as

```
if(someVariable.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(anotherVariable.GetType()))
```

You can view the documentation about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Unlike `if(someVariable.GetType() == anotherVariable.GetType())`, `is` also returns true if the type is a base type of the value's type. It also doesn't throw a NullReferenceException if `someVariable` is `null`. There are also some subtle differences when it comes to nullable types.

Answer (score 3):

It becomes more clear when you think about how "as" would be implemented. If "as" was a function:

```
public T as<T>(object obj){
    if(obj is T)
    {
        return (T) obj;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As this shows, T has to be a Nullable or a reference type because otherwise there would be no way to return null.

The "is" operator does no suffer from this problem because it returns a boolean and thus does not have to worry about if the target can be represented as null.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used with any type, since "is" considers boxing/unboxing.

```
int test = 4;
object test2 = test;
bool isTrue = (test2 is int);
```